# Handling events in Controller in JavaFX and MVC (Not FXML)

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx, event-handling, eventhandler

I'm learning JavaFx now and MVC and I'm trying to connect my button to the model through the Controller. I tried many ways to use `button.setOnActive(EventHandler e);`
but it doesn't work outside the view class
so what is the proper way to do it?

this is my View class

```
public class View extends Application{


private TextField num1;
private Label addLabel;
private TextField num2;;
public Button calcB;
private TextField sol;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Calculator");

    num1 = new TextField();
    addLabel = new Label("+");
    num2 = new TextField();

    calcB = new Button("Calculate");


    **// I'm trying to use this in the Controller
    calcB.setOnAction(event -> System.exit(0));**

    sol = new TextField();

    FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane();
    flowPane.getChildren().addAll(num1, addLabel, num2, calcB, sol);

    Scene scene = new Scene(flowPane, 600, 200);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();


}

public int getNum1(){
    return Integer.parseInt(num1.getText());
}

public int getNum2(){
    return Integer.parseInt(num2.getText());
}

public void setSol(int sol){
    this.sol.setText(Integer.toString(sol));
}
```

and this is my Controller Class

```
public class Controller{


private View  theView;
private Model theModel;

public Controller(Button b, EventHandler<ActionEvent> e) {
    this.theView = theView;
    this.theModel = theModel;

    **//SetOnActive() method should be somewhere in this Class**

}
```

I know that I should connect the button to a method in the model but right now I just want to know how I can make it work.

My model

```
public class Model {
private int calculationValue;

public  void addTwoNumbers(int firstNumber, int secondNumber){

    calculationValue = firstNumber + secondNumber;
}

public int getCalculationValue() {
    return calculationValue;
}
```

}

this is my main too

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){
    View view = new View();
    Model model = new Model();
    Controller controller = new Controller(view, model);

    Application.launch(View.class, args);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense for the view class to be a subclass of `Application `

Comment: How do you expect that your controller is actually able to control the elements when you never create one? Like this your `Controller` class isn't supposed to support in any way whatsoever. There is no connection between your Application and the Controller. That's was FXML does very convieniently under the hood.

Comment: I am new to it. Isn't like swing whenever you want to make gui you should inherit JFrame?

Comment: I added my main method can you look to it now?

Comment: I know fxml is much better but I don't want to use it now so, is there any way to make it work? I saw it work in swing but not javafx.

Comment: Well you don't have to extend `JFrame` in swing; I have certainly never done that in my swing applications. Even if you do, `JFrame` represents a window, so it's certainly not the equivalent of `Application`

Comment: @James_D then how can I use its method?

Comment: Is there a constructor mssing? `new Controller(view, model)` makes no sense at all... Try to use the `Controler` as a field in your View class.,  create the button and pass it by the controler when you instantiate it.

Comment: I think you need to back up and learn the basics of JavaFX. This question can't really be answered except by providing a complete tutorial. The `Application ` class is supposed to be the entry point of the application, and the `start()` method replaces the main method. Start with something simple and learn the basic life cycle, etc, before you leap into something complex.

Comment: @MadMatts My bad. there is a model class I forgot to add it and basically I followed a tutorial for swing and then wanted to convert it to JavaFx but it doesn't Work!

Comment: @James_D I followed thenewboston tutorial on youtube and that what he said "Extending Application"

Comment: @James_D  Also when I make a new javafx class in Intellij it extends Application by default

Comment: As I said, the `Application` class represents the entire application (specifically its lifecycle). You can't use it as a view. Does it make sense to say "a view *is an* application"?

Comment: Make the view class a separate class that isn't the application subclass. In the start method of the application class, instantiate the model, view(s) and controller(s),  connect them together, and display a view in the primary stage. If you have a `main(...)` method the  *only* thing it should do is call launch.

Comment: @James_D Sorry but I can't get it. what makes me doing this is I don't know how to make my app in MVC pattern. Please, can you tell me how can I divide my app in MVC pattern without using fxml? where should I draw my UI? Where should I put my logic and where should I connect them?

Comment: Well basically you have to wire all of the 3 parts with each other either directly or via an observable. For starters just assign every class a field for each other class

Comment: @MadMatts so you mean whether I have to make a 4th class and connect my other classes in it or I should make objects in each class of the other two?

Comment: Connect them together in the start method of the `Application` subclass. That's where the application starts

Comment: Exactly, that’s your entry point. Build your architecture from there, eg. in the `start` method

Comment: is this good? >>public class Test extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Calculator");
        View v= new View();
        Model m = new Model();
        Controller c = new Controller(v, m);
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setCenter(v.getPane());

        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 600, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a blank project with a ControllerA, ControllerB, Driver, ViewA, and ViewB classes using the code below, then run the code from the main method within the Driver class.

This should hopefully show you how events can be handled by a controller.

#### Driver:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Driver extends Application {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {}

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final Scene scene = new Scene(new ControllerA(primaryStage).getView());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

#### ControllerA:

```
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ControllerA implements EventHandler {
    private final Stage primaryStage;
    private final ViewA view = new ViewA(this);

    public ControllerA(final Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(final Event event) {
        final Object source = event.getSource();

        if (source.equals(view.getButton())) {
            System.out.println("ButtonA has been pressed, switching to ViewB.");

            final ControllerB controllerB = new ControllerB(primaryStage);
            final Scene scene = new Scene(controllerB.getView());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        }
    }

    public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }

    public ViewA getView() {
        return view;
    }
}
```

#### ViewA:

```
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

public class ViewA extends HBox {
    private final Button button = new Button("ButtonA");

    public ViewA(final ControllerA controllerA) {
        button.setOnAction(controllerA);
        this.getChildren().addAll(button);
    }

    public Button getButton() {
        return button;
    }
}
```

#### ControllerB:

```
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ControllerB {
    private final Stage primaryStage;
    private final ViewB view = new ViewB(this);

    public ControllerB(final Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    }

    public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }

    public ViewB getView() {
        return view;
    }
}
```

### View B:

```
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ViewB extends HBox {
    private final Button button = new Button("ButtonB");

    public ViewB(final ControllerB controllerB) {
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            System.out.println("ButtonB has been pressed, switching to ViewA.");

            final Stage primaryStage = controllerB.getPrimaryStage();
            final ControllerA controllerA = new ControllerA(primaryStage);
            final Scene scene = new Scene(controllerA.getView());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        });
        this.getChildren().addAll(button);
    }

    public Button getButton() {
        return button;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, Actually this make it more clearer buy I got some questions

Comment: thanks, Actually this make it more clearer buy I got some questions. What about if I have more the event to handle, can't I use something like lambda to make it clearer? Should I make another class for methods only? What about if I have more than scene and want to switch between them, where can I do that?

Comment: I've updated my post to include examples of using lambda and switching scenes. You do not need to create a separate class for handling methods (do you mean events?) as this is the core purpose of a Controller.

Comment: I want one menu for my whole app and another left menu to change the view of the center. I have another question which may make you understand what I want [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41314427/how-to-have-multiple-controller-in-mvc-javafx-not-fxml). Also, look at this picture please [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9j01ao9wt17bpin/Controller%20structure_0.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: The question is about MVC. For dummies like me the answer could be improved by adding a Model. Thanks